# How to redirect users to a mobile app in Django view?

Tags: django, django-views, universal-link

I have a Django web application and I'm trying to redirect users to my mobile app in one of the views.

```
def magic_link(request, token):
    return redirect(f"{settings.FRONTEND_URL}/magic_link/{token}")
```

This redirect link is like: `appname://magic_link/token`. However, I'm getting the following error.

```
DisallowedRedirect at /magic_link/{token}/
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'appname'
```

How can I fix this issue and redirect users to the mobile app in Django view?

Comment: you are actually rederecting user with "appname" protocol which doesnt exist, instead of "appname" should be "http" or "https" or "ftp" etc, how does your {settings.FRONTEND_URL} looks like ?

Comment: It's written in my question. ```settings.FRONTEND_URL``` is like ```appname:/```.

Comment: yes, this is your problem, can you access "appname://google.com" ? you are using it as a protocol it should be "http:/ /magic_link/token"

Comment: because this is a mobile app link. so what's the solution?

Comment: you cant redirect user on your server with django in your mobile app, it should be done inside mobile app, using your django with API

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own HttpResponsePermanentRedirect which inherits from HttpResponsePermanentRedirect by django. In your own class, you add your app scheme to the allow_schemes (something relevant, i can't remember so well)
to let django know your app scheme is valid.

Example:

```
class HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(HttpResponsePermanentRedirect by django):
   allow_schemes=['your_app_scheme',...]
```

Comment: Correct, you can do this with any class that inherits from `HttpResponseRedirectBase`. Strangely can't find any docs, but here's the source https://github.com/django/django/blob/1a78ef2b85467a18ea6d7eaa4b27f67d11c87b9e/django/http/response.py#L569